# ng-click not working on programatically triggering click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I used jQuery many times I am new to angular js.

I called a function on click event of a link. When i click on link it work fine and code is as below

```
<div data-ng-controller="myCtrl" >    
<a id="clickBtn" data-ng-click="clickDetails()" ></a>
</div>
```

But when i trigger the click event programmatically on page load. This function not called "clickDetails". I am triggering click event using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#clickBtn').trigger('click');
});
```

Any hint or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Comment: What are you trying to achive by using JQuery?

Comment: You can make an initial call to `clickDetails` in `myCtrl`, since controller is created at each view, you will be sure that `clickDetails` will be called for each view request.

Comment: @cubbuk I need to show an message to user untill he close that message box. Message box and anchor is dynamic. So, i keep the id of anchor into a cookie and on page load use that cookie to identify which message will be display. There are multiple messages.

Answer (score 1):

```
$timeout(function () {
    angular.element(document.getElementById('clickBtn')).triggerHandler('click');
}, 0);
```

try it?

http://jsfiddle.net/90nnmv6s/